# mysql "can't create test file" error on Centos

Tags: mysql, centos

When starting mysql on Centos servers with a custom data directory you might get an error similar to the following:

```
2014-10-15 10:23:56 17081 [Warning] Can't create test file /database/mysql/localhost.lower-test
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your chmod and chown settings are already correct you might need to look into selinux.
This page explains how to configure selinux for mysql:
https://blogs.oracle.com/jsmyth/entry/selinux_and_mysql

Comment: And what if selinux is disabled and this still happens?

Comment: If selinux is disabled. Then you need to check your chmod/chown settings. Another thing you can check is if your harddrive is full. Also check out Uwe's answer above. It could be helpful in your case.

Comment: None of the above.
The new MariaDB 10.1 adds some weird protection to Systemd service file. I'm gonna write a FIX i discovered as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you tried fixing ownership and permissions.

```
chown -R mysql:mysql /new-path/mysql
chmod 0755 /new-path/mysql
```

And you do not have **SELinux** enabled but you still have a problem.
All you need to do is to edit `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

```
ProtectSystem=full
ProtectHome=true
```

and **undefine** those variables (setting it to false won't work)

```
ProtectSystem=
ProtectHome=
```

And reload daemon

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

After I did this it finally worked. Interesting is that this occurs only with **MariaDB 10.1** 
Those variables are not existent for earlier versions.
Recently I have found this bug:

https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13896

**EDIT:**

Since this configuration gets overwritten after a MariaDB update, I have found a permanent fix to avoid any further downtime because of this.

```
cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service
```

Then I made changes here instead

```
vi /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

When running on CentOS 7, check out the systemd unit files which may prevent writing to / protect non-MySQL directories like `/home`.

The unit files lives in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`.